# opencv 3.2.0 java Face Recognition Ubuntu

Tags: java, opencv, ubuntu, face-recognition

i am using opencv 3.2.0 and im trying to get the face recognition up and running.

I am faced with the problem that the Face class in org.opencv.face.Face being empty. This is all contained in the file :

```
 //
 // This file is auto-generated. Please don't modify it!
 //
 package org.opencv.face;
 public class Face {
 }
```

From what i have read i need to add 'java' to the CMakeLists.txt of Face contrib module in order to add it to the final jar such as

```
ocv_define_module(face opencv_core opencv_imgproc opencv_objdetect WRAP python java)
```

In order to tell the compiler to include the contrib modules i have to add

```
 -D 
 OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=$YOUR_OPENCV_CONTRIB_PATH/opencv_contrib-
 3.2.0/modules
```

to the cmake command , and later make it , in general my commands are as follows

```
1: cmake 
2: make -j5
```

I get no errors when compiling and building and i get my jar,
which i use without issues for face detection and so forth. 
The problem is that the Face class is empty and i cannot create a FaceRecognizer.
i was following this guide here
https://github.com/andreaiacono/OpenCVDemo   -  as of 01.06.2017
and in the org.opencv.demo.core.RecognizerFactory class he uses

```
return Face.createFisherFaceRecognizer();
```

which as it seems i can not use.

I tried to search if the 3.2.0 libraries have a different way of creating a recognizer but google is not very helpful as there are just a handful of answers to any java opencv related issues.

What could be causing the Face class to be empty and/or are there any other ways to create recognizers in case that 3.2.0 indeed works differently ?

Thank you for the time

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer to my previous question and i am posting it for all to see , i hope i could help some other lost soul like myself.

I have tested with version 3.1.0 and it would appear that the Face class is **NOT** empty. Proving that Face detection in 3.2.0 may not be implemented properly (as of the time of writing).

I faced issues with compiling properly due to usage of some libraries :

```
 /usr/include/c++/6.1.1/cstdlib:75:25: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
 #include_next <stdlib.h>
```

An answer i found to this issue was found in https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6517#issuecomment-219219767

namely to include this in the cmake :

```
cmake -DENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF
```

This allowed me to compile everything properly and i managed to get my face recognition code up and running :)

Good luck to all